# Draw a horizontal line from the left margin to the end of centered text

Tags: margins, underline

I would like to draw a horizontal line from the left margin of the current page to the end of a centered text. For example, if I write "Hello, world!" as centered text, I would like a line spanning up to the "!" symbol, like an underlining.

I would like to avoid using `tikz`. Also, this should work for different texts (not just "Hello, world!"), so I would like to avoid having to hard-code the length or passing it as an argument.

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: \hrulefill may be what you are looking for

Comment: a single-lined text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The call to `\ulcenterline` causes a new paragraph.  Is that OK?  Or is to occur on the same line if there is already text on the left margin?  The line `\usepackage[showframe,pass]{geometry}` is just there to show the frame about the text area of the page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe,pass]{geometry}
\newcommand\ulcenterline[1]{%
  \par\noindent
  \rlap{\underline{\vphantom{#1}\rule{.5\linewidth}{0pt}}}%
  \centerline{\underline{#1}}%
}
\begin{document}
\ulcenterline{Hello World!}

\ulcenterline{This is a bigger test!!}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you need it to work without adding a `\par`, even if there is already text on the left-hand end of theline, then in my MWE, replace `\par` with `\tabto*{0pt}`, making sure to `\usepackage{tabto}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabto}
\newcommand\ulcenterline[1]{%
  \tabto*{0pt}\noindent
  \rlap{\underline{\vphantom{#1}\rule{.5\linewidth}{0pt}}}%
  \centerline{\underline{#1}}%
}
\begin{document}
xxx\ulcenterline{Hello World!}

text already on line\ulcenterline{This is a bigger test!!}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Beautiful!!! It works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: I can’t understand why `\leavevmode` after `\noindent`… ;-)

Comment: @GuM It used to be that `\rlap` wouldn't automatically leave vertical mode, so that `\rlap` wouldn't work as expected if issued after a `\par`.  But with the DEC 18 change to the engine, which "fixed" `\smash` and `\phantom`, maybe `\rlap` got fixed too.  The `\noindent` was so that the initial `\rule` is set from the left margin, rather than the indent position.

Comment: @GuM Perhaps you are telling me that `\noindent` already leaves vertical mode?

Comment: Exactly: `\noindent` causes TeX to enter (unrestricted) horizontal mode.  And no, also in `LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>`, the meaning of `\rlap` is still `macro:#1->\hb@xt@ \z@ {#1\hss }` (as it has always been).

Comment: @GuM Thanks.  Fixed.